# BWA: ./configure problem

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, configure

I have installed *Ubuntu 15.04* and installed one software *BWA* where it had a problem when I run command `./configure` It gives Error

```
 no such file or directory
```

Comment: The question is vague and unclear. Please clarify what you've installed, and copy/paste the installation log.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing applications from source](/q/123077)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not in that directory where configure file reside. so, you have to change directory to bwa directory and run command `./configure`  it will work. 
or 
if you are facing problem to install `bwa` then follow step bellow

install git using

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install git
```

then run command

```
git clone https://github.com/lh3/bwa.git
cd bwa; make
./bwa index ref.fa
./bwa mem ref.fa read-se.fq.gz | gzip -3 > aln-se.sam.gz
./bwa mem ref.fa read1.fq read2.fq | gzip -3 > aln-pe.sam.gz
```

i hope it will resolve your problem . for more info [here](https://github.com/lh3/bwa)

Comment: Make sure compile time dependencies are satisfied: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`